# can not get my simple code to work properly I am watching a tutorial and I am following each step

Tags: javascript

[screen shot from the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVOBD.png)I am a noob and going throw a course. pls help me identify the problem here [screen shot form my code VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8jlN.png)

thanks for help in advance !

here is the a screen shot from the course.

Comment: Welcome. It’s better to include the code in your post, not a screen shot, and also you need to describe the expected behaviour and what you are seeing.

Comment: Pay attention that these quotes ' ' are different from these ` `

Comment: @afarrag -- The quotes here are appropriate, given the variable `${literal}` being used.

Comment: Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is space between `$` and `{yearsLeft}` in your `console.log`. Try this one: `...${yearLeft}...`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to type ${yearLeft}, but not year**s**Left. But better to attach code and describe what you have and expectations instead of just photo attachment.

Answer (score 0):

remove the space in between `$` and `{yearsLeft}`

should be `${yearsLeft}` not `$ {yearsLeft}`